# reference function in object in another key function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, object

I have an module exported as the following, I want to call function in another is that possible in that case

```
module.exports = {
  first:() => {
    // this is my first function
  },
  second:() => {
    // I want to call my first function here
    // I have tried this 
    this.first()

  }
}
```

Comment: you can define the functions before exporting and reuse them however you want.

Comment: Ok I know this way but I thought there is might be another way to do it as it is

Comment: Wouldn’t just using a normal function instead of an arrow function fix the issue?

Comment: I have used the function keyword but it didn't solve it @strahinja

Comment: It give me this error
this.first is not a function @strahinja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `module.exports` at first in a variable and use it in `second` as follows:

**First file (other.js):**

```
const _this = (module.exports = {
  first: () => {
    console.log("first");
  },
  second: () => {
    _this.first();
  }
});
```

**Second file (index.js):**

```
import other from "./other";

other.second();
```

**Output:**

```
first
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it from the other module like this

```
const {first, second } = require('./module2');
first();
second();
```

or

```
const collectedFunctions = require('./module2');

collectedFunctions.first();
collectedFunctions.second();
```